# Make div follow screen wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make that the text follows the screen when u scroll,

I have placed all my text in a div named "mydiv"

```
<div id="mydiv" > 
    <!-- lots of stuff in asp -->
    <table>
        <!-- table rows, etc. -->
    </table>
</div>
```

The Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var currentTop = parseInt($('#mydiv').css('top'));
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('#mydiv').css('top', top+currentTop);
        });

    });

</script>
```

and this is my css

```
.mydiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the least amount of code that represents your problem. Also, please remove the extra space you have in your question.

Comment: Your markup is really bad. A few comments: Don't use `&nbsp;` or `<br>` or tables for your layout. Use `<div>`, `<p>`, and `<span>` elements, and use CSS to style those elements with `padding` and `margin` values. Also, try to format your code a bit more carefully; take a look at the [markup guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info.

Comment: i am not trying to style, i am trying to do like i asked in the question :)

Comment: Doing like you asked in the question is a large part of the problem you're having. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `position: absolute` fixes it relative to the body. You want `position: fixed`, which fixes it relative to the window.

If you have content that is larger than the size of the box, you'll need to account for that with the `overflow` property, so that you will have scroll bars on the box. The user can then see all of the content, though not all at the same time of course. So your CSS would be:

```
.mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can drop the jQuery entirely; you don't need it as long as you have `position: fixed`.

Note, however, that this does *not* work for mobile browsers, which use a [viewport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport) concept: there is a view layered over the rendered "window" and the `fixed` element is locked to the window, not the viewport. In that case, you will need to come up with a Javascript solution, though preferably one that only fires if you are on a mobile device.

Comment: using position fixed, i only can display half on the text i have how should i solve that? because i want to display all the text on fixed, only get half

Comment: That probably has to do with the poor markup you've got. If you clean things up to use `<div>` and `<p>` elements to lay out the content, the box should respond correctly. You should look at a good overview of the CSS box model. [This](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) should get you started.

Comment: but it displays until the table, after that it wont display anymore

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not entirely sure how `position: fixed` and `<table>` pieces interact. This is part of why you need to fix your markup: don't use a table.

Comment: Also, you of course cannot *both* fix something to the top of the screen *and* view content in it that is longer than the length of the screen. You get one or the other, not both.

Comment: i tryid to remove the table still the same

Comment: You have a ton of `<br>` elements that make the length of the content longer. I looked; the `<table>` element should be *styled* fine, though it's still the wrong thing to do, but it should display. The problem is simply that you have too much content to display on a single screen.

Comment: so there is no solution to make it possible on some way? even if my content is bigger then the screen?

Comment: Broadly speaking, that is correct. You can create a box that is the full height of the screen and make it scrollable, however; I'll add the markup for that in a little while.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29950/discussion-between-kriistiian-and-chris-krycho)

Answer (score 0):

Try css `position: fixed` if you want an element to be positioned relative to the viewport.

And please clean up your question formatting as best you can in case others wish to help you and learn from your question.

Comment: i want my text to be positioned relative to my viewport, but my text are bigger then the viewport that i have so the rest text whant be displayed

Comment: Try setting `width:100%` to the div and a fixed height. Also check your `overflow` property of the div and make sure it's not set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: Fixed on the div that you want to 'follow the screen".

Comment: i want the holde code in the top to follow the screen, but only get half, because the screen aint bigger